# Video on Gooddrama not playing "You have no flash plugin installed"

Tags: 14.04, video

When I try to play videos from the 'Gooddrama' site I get an error message:

> Flash version 9,0 or greater is required, you have no flash plugin installed.

However, when I try to play YouTube videos they play without any problem. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: youtube mostly uses html now.

Comment: What web-browser are you using and do you, in fact, have Adobe Flash installed?

Comment: I'm using Mozilla firefox. I have VLC player installed . But I don't want to download those videos and play them using VLC, I want to play/view them directly from the website "gooddrama" , but the site keeps displaying the above error message. I already have Adobe Flash installed, but I am not sure which version.

Comment: Go to: http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ and post what version, if any, of Adobe Flash it tells you you are running.

Comment: Thanks!I visited the above site and checked the version, it said:Flash Player not installed or enabled. Then I installed the 11.2 Flash version and the video started playing.

Comment: Ok, right on.  You should add that as an answer yourself and then choose it as solved.  You solved your own issue so you won't get the reputation for it but it will provide closure for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I visited the  site  adobe.com/software/flash/about  and  checked the adobe version, it said:Flash Player not installed or enabled. Then I installed the 11.2 Flash version and the video  from the site 'Gooddrama' started playing.